# Simple File Manager with recursion in C#

Tags: c#

Simple class to simpify runtime file loading of ressources. The class reads all files from a given directory including all subdirectories and stores the name together with the path in a simple struct. If a file needs to be used by the program just pass the name to GetPath() and the class returns the location of the file.

Any suggestions/improvements about my implementation of this? Im especially not sure if making this static is the right choice.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Sample
{
    struct File
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Path;           
    }

    static class FileManager
    {        
        private static List<File> Files = new List<File>();        

        public static void AddFiles(string directory)
        {
            foreach(string file in  Directory.GetFiles(directory))
            {   
                Files.Add(new File() { Name = Path.GetFileName(file), Path = directory });
            }

            foreach(string subdirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(directory))
            {
                AddFiles(subdirectory);
            }
        }

        public static string GetPath(string filename)
        {
            var File = Files.Find(x => x.Name == filename);

            return File.Path;
        }

        public static void ClearFiles()
        {
            Files.Clear();
        } 
    }    
}
```

Comment: What is `Find` and how does it handle files with same names? Please add its implementation to the question. Oh, or not... I see it's a `List`'s method haha, I've never used it before ;-] and it returns the first match. Interesting. Is this what you want? Why don't you use `FirstOrDefault` which I find much cleaner because you clearly see what you'll get.

Comment: There should not be ressources with identical name and file ending. So Find() returning the first match is fine for the program. That being said, maybe i should consider checking the List for duplicates when filling it to raise an error when somehow two ressources with identical names do actually exist in different subdirectories.

Comment: What if files are added to a folder after the initial read? Is that something you need to support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think I would make this class static, unless it's going to be used extensively throughout the program. If not you can build up a large list of files, that may hang around in memory for no use, unless you remember to call `ClearFiles()`. Instead you could make a static method that could return an initialized object like:

```
public static FileManager Create(string directoryPath)
{
  FileManager fm = new FileManager();
  fm.AddFiles(directoryPath);
  return fm;
}
```

If you have a need for it, then make this instance as static somewhere in the application.

---

> ```
> public static string GetPath(string filename)
> {
>   var File = Files.Find(x => x.Name == filename);
>   return File.Path;
> }
> ```

It returns only a first match of possible more matches, which will be in a directory high in the hierarchy, but what if you actually seek a path to a file in a subdirectory?

I think I would return a list/array/IEnumerable instead and let the client filter as needed.

Besides that, file names are case insensitive, so you should do:

```
Files.Find(x => string.Equals(x.Name, filename, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

---

> ```
> public static void AddFiles(string directory)
> {
>   foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(directory))
>   {
>     Files.Add(new File() { Name = Path.GetFileName(file), Path = directory });
>   }
>   foreach (string subdirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(directory))
>   {
>     AddFiles(subdirectory);
>   }
> }
> ```

Nice recursive method. As an alternative you could consider to use `DirectoryInfo` instead - it can handle the recursive search for you:

```
  DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
  Files.AddRange(
    directory
    .GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Select(fi => new File { Name = fi.Name, Path = fi.DirectoryName }));
```

---

There is no way to iterate through all the found File objects because the `Files` static member is private. I would consider to provide a public IEnumerable of some kind.

---

All in all, my implementation would look something like:

```
  public struct File
  {
    public string Name;
    public string Path;

    public override string ToString()
    {
      return $"{Name} => {Path}";
    }
  }

  public class FileManager : IEnumerable<File>
  {
    private List<File> Files = new List<File>();

    public void AddFiles(string directoryPath)
    {
      DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
      Files.AddRange(
        directory
        .GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Select(fi => new File { Name = fi.Name, Path = fi.DirectoryName }));
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetPaths(string filename)
    {
      return Files
        .Where(x => string.Equals(x.Name, filename, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        .Select(f => f.Path);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
      Files.Clear();
    }

    public IEnumerator<File> GetEnumerator()
    {
      return Files.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
      return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public static FileManager Create(string directoryPath)
    {
      FileManager fm = new FileManager();
      fm.AddFiles(directoryPath);
      return fm;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Windows 10 supports marking directories/entire file systems as case-insensitive. It's not mentioned, but if this were dotnet core, then running on Linux/Mac would also support that. That said, if you're going to ignore case, I *believe* the proper thing to do for windows files (assuming case insensitivity) is to use `OrdinalIgnoreCase`

Comment: Too late to edit my comment, but that first line was supposed to read: Windows10 supports... case *sensitive*